# Logging in to vBulletin

Tags: python, authentication, vbulletin

I am trying to do a program in Python which logs in to a vBulletin forum.

I need to access only one page, but in order to view that page I must be logged in.

Here is my code:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, hashlib, time

def variables():
    domain = "www.example.com"
    uname = "UserName"
    passwd = "Password"

    # Create url
    if domain.startswith('http://'):
         url = domain
    else:
        url = 'http://' + domain

    login(url, uname, passwd)


def login(url, uname, passwd):
    loginurl = url + '/login.php?do=login'
    md5 = hashlib.md5(passwd);md5 = md5.hexdigest()
    # Options for request
    opts = {
        'do': 'login',
        'vb_login_md5password': md5,
        'vb_login_md5password_utf': md5,
        's': '',
        'vb_login_username': uname, 
        'security_token': 'guest', 
    }
    data = urllib.urlencode(opts)

    # Request header
    global headers
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Referer': loginurl,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Lenght': '205'
    }

    # Cookie Handling
    jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))

    # Send Request
    opener.addheader = headers
    opener.open(loginurl, data)

    # Check
    response = opener.open('http://example.com/usercp.php?variable')
    print response.read()


variables()
```

The problem is that it doesn't log me in and I can't find the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to send vb_login_name and vb_login_password to login.php?do=login

2) you need to send below values to login.php?do=login too (view html code)

```
<input type="hidden" name="s" value="215c619cb0227a30bab788ca0adb1c42" />
<input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="guest" />
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password" />
```

below line means you shoud md5hash the vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, vb_login_md5password_utf before you send these values to login.php

```
<form action="login.php?do=login" method="post" onsubmit="md5hash(vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, vb_login_md5password_utf, 0)">
```

---

HTTP POST data:  username=abc, password=123

```
POST /forums/login.php?do=login HTTP/1.1
Host: absolutewrite.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 216
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://absolutewrite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.0 Safari/535.11
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://absolutewrite.com/forums/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: UTF-8,*;q=0.5
Cookie: bbsessionhash=215c619cb0227a30bab788ca0adb1c42; bblastvisit=1323333120; bblastactivity=0

vb_login_username=abc&vb_login_password=&s=215c619cb0227a30bab788ca0adb1c42&securitytoken=guest&do=login&vb_login_md5password=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70&vb_login_md5password_utf=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
```

Comment: But that's what I'm doing, no? I md5hash the password, sending the options for the request (opts), and the HTTP headers, but it doesn't log me in.

Comment: in your code, you left the s value blank, but you need to fill it with the right value, your can view the html code to get it. in my sampe s value is 215c619cb0227a30bab788ca0adb1c42

Comment: 3) and in post data, you need to set cookie header. bbsessionhash=215c619cb0227a30bab788ca0adb1c42; (this value may be diffrent in your case)

Comment: I looked the data that sends the browser with the LiveHTTP Headers Firefox extension, and the value of s was empty. But I discovered that **it does log me in**, because the first opener content shows the page with "_Welcome back_"; now the problem is that even if I am logged in, when I access the usercp.php page it doesn't let me.

Comment: i tested your code on http://bbs.jjol.cn, it worked fine. i can access  http://bbs.jjol.cn/usercp.php?variable page. sorry, i don't know what is wrong. please check your site or test your code on other site. good luck