# Connect vBulletin 4.2.2 forum with Python

Tags: python, vb.net, md5, vbulletin

I read this page and the code doesn't work still:
[Logging in to vBulletin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427289/logging-in-to-vbulletin)

My code:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, hashlib, time

def variables():
    domain = "www.example.com"
    uname = "UserName"
    passwd = "Password"

    # Create url
    if domain.startswith('http://'):
         url = domain
    else:
        url = 'http://' + domain

    login(url, uname, passwd)


def login(url, uname, passwd):
    loginurl = url + '/login.php?do=login'
    md5 = hashlib.md5(passwd);md5 = md5.hexdigest()
    # Options for request
    opts = {
        'do': 'login',
        'vb_login_md5password': md5,
        'vb_login_md5password_utf': md5,
        's': '',
        'vb_login_username': uname, 
        'security_token': 'guest', 
    }
    data = urllib.urlencode(opts)

    # Request header
    global headers
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Referer': loginurl,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Lenght': '205'
    }

    # Cookie Handling
    jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))

    # Send Request
    opener.addheader = headers
    opener.open(loginurl, data)

    # Check
    response = opener.open('http://example.com/')
    source_code = response.read()
    if source_code.find(uname) != -1:
        print "Login Succeeded."
    else:
        print "Login Failed."


variables()
```

The  property value of field name is None (Empty):

```
<input type="hidden" name="s" value="" />
```

Why the code doesn't work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Missing "vb_login_password","vb_login_password_hint","cookieuser",  and "vb_login_md5password_utf" must be empty.

And remove your header for sure.

Comment: What i should put in vb_login_password_hint and cookieuser?
If you can give me example with code, it will be very helpful.

Comment: Install Live HTTP Headers(only firefox will work) and open it then start to login, you will see the all POST request.

Comment: I installed Live HTTP Header in firefox and open it before i start login, and i saw all POST request and after that i filled all the input form accordingly, and i tried to login again without success. What is wrong?

Comment: I success to login the forum, but it works sometimes,after three times running the script, it's not login anymore. what the problem? how can i fixed it?